# SQL Finding Missing Dates Between Ranges

Tags: sql, database

I have a table of jobs that have ran for different source systems. These have a "RunDate" and then the `FromDate` and `ToDate`.

I want to find the gaps where we are missing any dates in the `FromDate` and `ToDate` fields to make sure that we have covered the data in those periods.

Many examples I've looked at work where a single date misses in a single column of ranges, however I have a From and To range that I need to test and ultimately work out where a date may be missed.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [SourceSystem] nchar(3), [RunDate] datetime, [ResubmitCount] int, [FromDate] date, [ToDate] date )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( N'ILG', N'2021-07-28T15:35:23.207', 0, N'2021-06-01T00:00:00', N'2021-06-01T00:00:00' ), 
( N'ILG', N'2021-07-28T15:35:23.707', 0, N'2021-06-05T00:00:00', N'2021-06-06T00:00:00' ), 
( N'AAP', N'2021-07-28T15:35:23.833', 0, N'2021-06-01T00:00:00', N'2021-06-02T00:00:00' ), 
( N'AAP', N'2021-07-28T15:35:23.833', 0, N'2021-06-04T00:00:00', N'2021-06-04T00:00:00' ), 
( N'ZZP', N'2021-07-28T15:35:23.897', 0, N'2021-06-05T00:00:00', N'2021-06-05T00:00:00' )

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

So obviously using the example above I should be able to ascertain that the period between `2021-06-02` and `2021-06-04` for SourceSystem `ILG` and period `2021-06-03` to `2021-06-03` is missing for SourceSystem `AAP`.

Struggling to make it work for ranges, I can work with single dates but the system doesn't log them in this fasion.

**UPDATE**

I took the accepted answer and then tagged some code to it to be able to explode all the individual dates between the ranges specified.

Included the code in case anyone needs in the future.

```
WITH
  a AS (
    SELECT
      SourceSystem, FromDate, ToDate,
      LEAD(FromDate) OVER(
        PARTITION BY SourceSystem
        ORDER BY RunDate
      ) AS NextDate
    FROM dbo.WDSubmission ws
  ),
  gap_periods AS
  (
SELECT
  SourceSystem,
  DATEADD(DAY, 1, ToDate) AS GapBeg,
  DATEADD(DAY, -1, NextDate) AS GapFin
FROM a
WHERE
  NextDate IS NOT NULL AND
  DATEADD(DAY, -2, NextDate) >= ToDate
  --AND a.SourceSystem = 'OGI'  
  )  , E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)
    ,E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b)
    ,E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b)
    ,E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b)
    ,E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b)
    ,E32(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E16 a, E16 b)
    ,cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E32)
    ,DateRange AS
(
    SELECT ExplodedDate = DATEADD(DAY,N - 1,'2021-01-01')
    FROM cteTally
    WHERE N <= DATEDIFF(DAY,'2021-01-01',GETDATE())
)
SELECT *
FROM gap_periods eh
JOIN DateRange d ON d.ExplodedDate >= eh.GapBeg
 AND d.ExplodedDate <= eh.GapFin;
```

Comment: Your data has three dates.  That makes the question a bit hard to follow.  You should also provide a database tag.

Comment: You need a calendar table or a tally to select from dates not covered by any (FromDate , ToDate) interval in #temptable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff have added the db tag and also highlighted the fields in quesiton I'm querying about.

Comment: Search for "packing date intervals" on SO. Basically you combine consecutive/overlapping date ranges together, then if you end up with two or more rows then end date of one row and start date of next row represents a gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH
  a AS (
    SELECT
      SourceSystem, FromDate, ToDate,
      LEAD(FromDate) OVER(
        PARTITION BY SourceSystem
        ORDER BY RunDate
      ) AS NextDate
    FROM #temptable
  )
SELECT
  SourceSystem,
  DATEADD(DAY, 1, ToDate) AS GapBeg,
  DATEADD(DAY, -1, NextDate) AS GapFin
FROM a
WHERE
  NextDate IS NOT NULL AND
  DATEADD(DAY, -2, NextDate) >= ToDate;
```

Result:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+
| SourceSystem |   GapBeg   |   GapFin   |
+--------------+------------+------------+
| AAP          | 2021-06-03 | 2021-06-03 |
| ILG          | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-04 |
+--------------+------------+------------+
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=afa0952ff1b609bdc0ea007f3d41bc36)

Comment: Andrei, this looks like pretty much what I'm looking for, is there anyway I could output each individual gap as an individual date. so I know for ILG 02/06, 03/6 and 04/06 is missing but could I list them as those individual dates rather than the gap itself?

Comment: Scratch that - have updated my question and given you the tick for the answer Andrei - Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to display the missing dates and also it would be too much information to analyze. Bbut you can get the number of days skipped in between using the below query :

```
select *,datediff(day,lag(ToDate)over(partition by sourcesystem order by ToDate),fromdate) from #temptable
```

The data would look something like this (last column tells the number of days skipped) :

[image]